# Modeling Analysis service tabular fact with many columns

Tags: modeling, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

I have a tabular analysis service fact table with more than 150 attributes (degenrate) and measures (Invoice fact table).

I would like to improve the user experience when browsing the table on azure AS.
Is it a good idea to split the table horizontally to 3 tables each table contains a set of columns and measures (the number of rows remains the same on 3 tables) ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't change a model for browsing's sake. Browsing is a reporting issue. Modeling is modeling. Build a good dimensional model in a star schema. Big wide tables are bad.

I would look for anything that ought to be a dimension to pull out, and build some junk dimensions, and for sure I would move the measures to a DAX table. But if whatever is left is ugly, then I would just leave it and build a report for browsing.

Comment: Is it a good practice to have a dimension table for invoice where I put the attributes of invoices and a fact table that have facts related to invoives (fact invoice would have a 1-1 relationship with dim invoice)